# Something weird about returning NAs

Tags: r, sum, na

this is a lame question I guess, but i don't understand what's is happining. If I go:

```
sum(is.na(census$wd))
```

It returns 4205

But if I go with:

```
sum(census$wd == NA)
```

It returns "NA"

I just would like to understand whats is happening. If I do str(census), wd shows up as:

```
$ wd         : num  NA 0.65 0.65 0.65 0.78 0.78 0.78 0.78 0.78 0.78 ...
```

Can anyone explains why the codes return different outputs? Thank you!

Comment: Because `==` isn't how you identify `NA`s. Type `NA == NA` at the console and see.

Answer (score 4):

`==` in `R` is a comparison. But you can not compare something to `NA` in `R`as the following quote from `?Comparison` states:

> Missing values (NA) and NaN values are regarded as non-comparable even
>   to themselves, so comparisons involving them will always result in NA.

In contrast `is.na` indicates which elements are missing regardless of their type.
So it returns a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` entries.

```
> a <- c(NA,1,2,3)
> a == NA
[1] NA NA NA NA

> is.na(a)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

this is why `sum` is working with `is.na` (interpreting `TRUE=1` and `FALSE=0` but it cannot sum up a vector of `NA`'s (generated by `==NA`)